# FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine app.dockerfile results in fastcgi error when adding sh file to run as an entrypoint

Tags: php-fpm, fastcgi, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, php-fastcgi

I am using AWS ECS Faragate to generate and deploy docker containers into tasks.

I'm using the docker image FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine for my app container.

I have been working on a workaround for cron type solution to the app container. This solution runs a php yii2 command and then sleeps for 1m, in a while loop.

The app container is now resulting in the following error message, which is not resulting in the task definition to persist, and to constantly restart, here is the error I am receiving from my app container:

```
[error] 22#22: *135 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.19.236, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "10.0.2.163"
```

As a result, to try and get around this error. I updated my fastcgi_pass to app:9000 but got the following error from the app container:

```
[emerg] 7#7: host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:35
```

I have attached the code changes I made during the process.

[image: code changes]

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

I was reading that maybe I need to create the bash script on a different thread to the main one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The configs don't show a container named `app`.